# SSRS Opening Active Directory Folder

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, sharepoint, reporting-services, microsoft-edge

Hi our Internet Explorer 11 is going to be retired, and we are facing an issue in opening a folder link in our SharePoint to a "file:////" folder.  This method does not work in Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome.  I checked the SSRS available option on Action, but i don't see option to open a folder file.  Has anyone able to open a file folder directory using SSRS?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with any recent browser anymore. There are plugin's available that report that they can get round this (I have personally not tested these) such as https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=en

Comment: Firefox might be able to with some policy changes: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1264779 . It seems like people have been asking MS about it but they are steerign user to sharepoint. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/how-the-new-edge-will-handle-file-uri/m-p/425906

Comment: I wish i can decide on what browser to use, but Edge will be our corporate browser soon so I guess i'm out of luck.  Thanks guys

Comment: Like what said in the above comments, Edge/Chrome doesn't support `file:////` protocol, you can use the extension which is recommended in the first comment or open them in Edge with Edge IE mode. Edge IE mode uses IE engine so it will work.